# 1.9 Validation returns true but error message appears when other are wrong

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, customer-account, validation

I've implemented a new function to validate a single date field with format 'dd/mm/YYYY'. It works well but if another field is wrong, it's error message appears.

Here is my js

```
var frenchDateReg = /^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/g;    
Validation.add('validate-date-fr', 'Please enter a correct date. For example 24/12/2017', function(v) {
        console.log(v);
        console.log(Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v));
        console.log(frenchDateReg.test(v));
        console.log(frenchDateReg);
        return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || frenchDateReg.test(v)
    });
```

on log when error appears and not I have the same showing :

```
[Log] 05/05/1995 (fonctions.js, line 8)
[Log] false (fonctions.js, line 9)
[Log] true (fonctions.js, line 10)
[Log] /^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/g (fonctions.js, line 11)
```

But in front I get the error :
[image]
Theses fields are in the customer edit form. So to generate the date field I override the template customer/account/widget/dob.phtml like this :

```
<label for="dob"<?php if ($this->isRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->__('Date of birth') ?></label>
<div class="input-box customer-dob">
    <?php
    $time = $this->getTime();
    $date = null;
    if ($time) {
        $date = $this->getDay().'/'.$this->getMonth().'/'.$this->getYear();
    }
    ?>
    <input type="text" id="dob" name="dob" value="<?php echo $date ?>" title="dob" class="input-text required-entry validate-date-fr" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Fill this field') ?>" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var customer_dob = new Varien.DOB('.customer-dob', <?php echo $this->isRequired() ? 'true' : 'false' ?>, '<?php echo $this->getDateFormat() ?>');
    //]]>
</script>
```

Can you help me please ? I don't understand why the error is showing with a correct js validation return.

Answer (score 0):

IDK why this bug but with this js, the error not appears again :

```
Validation.add('validate-date-fr', 'Please enter a correct date. For example 24/12/2017', function(v) {
        return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/g.test(v)
    });
```